# Get component under mouseReleased

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to do something similar to this: [Swing - Get new component under mouseReleased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476454/swing-get-new-component-under-mousereleased)

In a window, I have some buttons with a number on each one. For example 2 8 5 6. This would show 4 JButtons. If I press the mouse on 2, drag and release on 8... I'd like `firstcomponent` to contain the JButton 2 and `lastcomponent` to contain the JButton with 8.

```
public class Bouton extends JButton implements MouseListener {

String name;
Component firstEntered; 
Component lastEntered;

public Bouton(String str) {
    super(str);
    this.name = str;
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) { }

 @Override
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) { 
     lastEntered = event.getComponent();
     String name2 = ((JButton) lastEntered).getName();
     System.out.println("entered : " + name2);
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) { 
    firstEntered = event.getComponent();
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) { 
    // I tried this didn't work...
    //firstEntered = event.getComponent();
}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) { 
    firstEntered.setBackground(Color.RED);
    lastEntered.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    String name = ((JButton) firstEntered).getName();
    String name2 = ((JButton) lastEntered).getName();
    System.out.println("Release ... first: " + name);
    System.out.println("Release ... last entered: " + name2);
}    

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

The output is :

```
entered : 2
entered : 8
Release ... first: 2
Release ... last entered: 2
```

My problem is I don't understand why "Release ... last entered: 2" shows 2. Why it isn't 8 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Bouton` you add has it's own `firstEntered` and `lastEntered`, therefore it can only correctly print out the current button (`this`). My suggestion would be to create *only one* new instance of a `MouseListener`, I don't think there's a need to make an own `JButton`: (The `mousePressed()` method also works properly now)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener(); // Only one MouseListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            b.addMouseListener(ml); // Add the same MouseListener to every
                                    // button
            p.add(b);
        }
        frame.setContentPane(p);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {

        Component firstEntered;
        Component lastEntered;

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
            lastEntered = event.getComponent();
            System.out.println("entered : " + ((JButton) lastEntered).getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            firstEntered = event.getComponent();
            System.out.println("pressed : " + ((JButton) event.getComponent()).getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            firstEntered.setBackground(Color.RED);
            lastEntered.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            System.out.println("Release ... first: " + ((JButton) firstEntered).getText());
            System.out.println("Release ... last entered: " + ((JButton) lastEntered).getText());
        }
    }

}
```